# What's wrong with my VHDL testbench?

Tags: vhdl

I've created a testbench to test an adder carry circuit (although it doesn't matter what the circuit is doing)

You can see below that I'm getting 'Error' failures spit out from my testbench.At 261901ps, I show values here in the isim debugger.. test_s(8) and (0) are both '1' and cout is '1'.

[image]

Now, my testbench looks like this:

```
ASSERT (test_s(8) = cout)
    REPORT "Carry out failed for cin = 1!";
```

So what's wrong?  I also tried /= cout just in case.. and I seem to get the same thing.  What I want is to say, if test_s MSB (8) is different than cout, then issue an error because that's broken behavior

Cout is std_logic;
test_s is std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);

Comment: Apparently the values in the waveform are different from those in the Objects window, and consistent with the assertion error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VHDL is correct. You are asserting that test_s(8) should be equal to cout and you report when it is not.

At the cursor on your waveform, test_s(8) is 0 and cout is 1. Your assert is detecting this and reporting it.